# Memory/CPU statistics for transaction logs (MSSQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, transactions

i need to see transaction activities' in terms of cpu/memory usage. For example, which transaction occupy memory or cpu most?

Comment: Add the tag of DBMS you are using

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: `select * From sys.dm_exec_requests`

Comment: for current session sys.dm_exec_sessions;

Answer (score 0):

There is number DMV having the information you need. I recommend reading [this](https://www.red-gate.com/library/performance-tuning-with-sql-server-dynamic-management-views) book about them if you need some insight. Sometimes I use this query to fetch the information about the actual running transactions:

```
SELECT S.login_name,
       S.host_name,
       S.program_name,
       R.command,
       T.text,
       R.transaction_id,
       R.cpu_time,
       R.granted_query_memory,
       R.wait_type,
       R.wait_time,
       R.blocking_session_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS R
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS S ON R.session_id = S.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(R.sql_handle) AS T
WHERE S.is_user_process = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you but i need transaction id etc.

Comment: @BurakHak then you should specify the expected output better in the question! The `transaction_id` is part of `sys.dm_exec_requests`, if you had opened the book (or simply the documentation), you would find out. I have updated the answer.